# What vehicle is this GTA V Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So I need help identifying this vehicle in GTA V on PS4. If this is a standard vehicle then could you please tell me the name and where I can find it. If not and it is a custom vehicle, any way I could make it?

[image: Vehicle in question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [Brute Armored Boxville](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Armored_Boxville).  It's sold by Warstock Cache and Carry.

Comment: Added with the import/export DLC